# Difference between kubernetes recreate update strategy vs simply uninstall, install

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

When deciding on update strategy for a kubernetes application, there is an option to use `Recreate` strategy.

How would this be different from just uninstalling and installing the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by *"just uninstalling and installing the app"* you mean complete deletion of your deployment e.g.:

```
kubectl delete deployment nginx-deployment
```

and creating it again:

```
kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml
```

Note that when using `Recreate` strategy there is no complete deletion of the deployment so there is fundamental difference here. By choosing this strategy you only inform kubernetes that all the pods managed by your deployment should be deleted and recreated when you update them (e.g. you update the image version of the container) rather than deleting and recreating their new versions one at a time what takes place when using `RollingUpdate` strategy. This way you make sure that certain number of pods serving an old version of the application are still available when the update occurs and pods with a new version of the image appear.

When you delete your deployment and create a new one, your new deployment has nothing to do with the old one. In other words, completely new `Deployment` resource is created and no history of the changes you made is preserved.

I believe the best way of explaining things is always an example. So let's move on to the following one.

Let's say you've created a new nginx deployment based on your yaml manifest:

```
kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml
```

and then you decided to update the image version, either by editing `nginx-deployment.yaml` manifest and re-applying it or this way:

```
kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.161 --record=true
```

In either case you will be able to [check rollout history](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#checking-rollout-history-of-a-deployment) by running:

```
kubectl rollout history deployment nginx-deployment
```

and you should see something like this:

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment nginx-deployment 
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-deployment.yaml --record=true
2         kubectl set image deployment nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.16.1 --record=true
```

When you have rollout history you're able to undo your latest change and go back to the previous revision:

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment
```

Now your rollout history for this deployment may look like this:

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
2         kubectl set image deployment nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.16.1 --record=true
3         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-deployment.yaml --record=true
```

When you simply delete your deployment and recreate it again you will have nothing in rollout history for newly created deployment and you won't be able  to roll it back to some older revision in such an easy way.

Comment: so the only difference is "recreate" will maintain a rollout history and uninstall/install will not. is that correct ?

Answer (score 2):

`Recreate` strategy will delete your Pods and then add new Pods - you will get short downtime, but on the other side you will not use much extra resources during upgrade.

You typically want `RollingUpgrade` since that takes a few Pods at a time and you can deploy stateless applications without downtime.